# Assign formula for an excel column using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, excel-formula

I want to set the formula frmo B5 to B10004, the formula depends on the previous column's value. But the formula should dynamically update the cell references appropriately

```
dvCarConstraint = 
    DVConstraint.createFormulaListConstraint(
        "INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE($B$5, \" \", \"_\"))"
    );

addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(4, 10004, 2, 2);
dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressCarList, dvCarConstraint);
dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
sheet.addValidationData(dataCarValidation);
```

When I open the excel all the cells in the column shows `INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE($B$5, " ", "_"))`, whereas what I expect is `INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE($B$6, " ", "_")), $B$7` and so on....

How to do this in POI ?

Comment: If you set the same thing up in Excel, then read the file in POI, what does it show the formula as being?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know POI, but in excel if you want the formula to be updated according to cell position you leave off the $-sign. Have you tried `INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE($B5, " ", ""))`?

Answer (score 0):

I know its a very old question but for other people who are facing the same problem can maybe use this solution:-

I faced the same problem and after trying some combinations reached to this which worked fine for me.

```
INDIRECT(UPPER($A1:$A500))
```